# Grant Access Using Hierarchies Read vs. Edit

Tags: sharing

I can't remember and I can't find it anywhere when I google. If I make Accounts Read Only in Org-Wide Default and check grant access using hierarchies does that mean the users above the owner in the Role hierarchy can read the record or read and edit the record?

Salesforce says it makes the record visible, is that just read? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_sharing_owd_about.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OWD is just the minimum level of access a user can have on a record. If you are using GUAH, then managers in the hierarchy automatically get Owner access to records owned by their subordinates, meaning they can edit, change ownership, and delete, records their subordinates own (assuming their profile allows them). GUAH also allows managers to have the same level of access to a record that their subordinates do, for example, because a record was manually shared with a user, or a sharing rule allowed additional access.

Comment: This was helpful. I could not remember it.